# Display Android Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to display the soft keyboard. I have found many answers but none of them solve my problem.
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(error[0], InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        error[0].requestFocus();

Answer (score 0):

Try This . When you activity starts, Soft Keyboard will popup :-

```
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or Add this to the activity on which you want to show soft keyboard when it starts :-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

or if you want soft keyboard to popup on an edit text :-

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```